# Composition of derived classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, composition

I have a question regarding composition and inheritance in C++:

I have a base class `'A'` and a derived class `'B'` (`'B'` inherits members from `'A'`), is it possible use `'B'` as a member of `'A'` by composition?

Comment: Not possible, because `A` would need to know the size of `B`, which contains an `A`, which contains a `B`, which....

Comment: This is hypothetical, right?  You don't have a real problem that you're trying to solve, do you?

Comment: yep, I'm just asking.
so if I will create class `'C'` that is derived from `'A'` and has a member `'B'`, it is possible, right?

Comment: @Medvednic Right.  In that case, you'll have exactly 2 instances of `A`, not infinite.

Comment: Yes, your `C : A { B b; };` is plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to "A has B member, B derived from A":  Practically, you cannot declare such a thing.  If class A has a member of type B, then B needs to be declared before A.  If B uses A as a base, A must be declared before B.

As to composition, if you wanted to do such a thing, you could have to use indirection (pointer, smart-pointer, etc).

```
class B;
class A {
  B *b;
};
class B : public A {
};
```

One might argue that (in C++) using pointers is not composition; however, in Java, all Objects are "pointers", so composition is:

```
class A {
  B b;
}
class B extends A {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

However you may embed a `B*` field. Hence a `const B&` should be possible too, and behave like a `B`. *(Mind I am now a sandbox java programmer.)*

```
class B;
class A {
    B& b;
};
```

BTW you might not even embed an A in an A.

Comment: You would still have the endless recursion.  You could cast `A::my_b` to an `A`, access its `my_b`, cast that to an `A`...

Comment: @DrewDormann that's not actually a problem : linked lists are structured similarly. Just know when to stop recursing.

Comment: @Quentin The use of a _reference variable_ in this answer would cause endless recursion.  For the same reason that linked lists don't use  references as their links.  There's no NULL, no "stop recursing" mechanism.

Comment: Why would there have to be such a "stop recusing" mechanism? [This example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74bde7b6f23f43dd) works. Since OP has not stated *why* they want this field, such a use can't be ruled out as impossible.

Comment: A reference `B&` is stored as a `B*`: `sizeof(B&) == sizeof(B*)`. Such a reference pointer is automatically dereference at its usage. @DrewDormann: right?

Comment: @JoopEggen: The standard makes no such requirement. `sizeof (B&) == sizeof (B)`, not `sizeof (B*)`. It may be common to implement references using pointers "under-the-hood", but this is not visible to C++ code.

Comment: @Mankarse thanks for the correction; I will check `sizeof(struct{B&})` (no C++) on occasion. So `class A { A& a; }` is not possible too?

Comment: @DrewDormann The "stop recursing" mechanism needs not be part of the reference, it can also be a sentinel value (think about circular linked lists, where you stop recursing when you're on a given "head" node).

Comment: @JoopEggen: `class A { A& a; }` is totally possible.

Comment: @Mankarse thanks (I have no C++ compiler at the workplace). Then I leave my answer undeleted, as others might find a use for it.